# Right censored data in survival analysis

Tags: survival, censoring

Hello I'm new to survival analysis and I have a question about right censored data processing.

[image]

For patient B, he survived through the entire study time. Therefore, we need to use the study end date to subtract the study start date to extract the survival days for patient B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this situation, the "survival days" for *all* individuals is the difference between the last observation date and the date of entry into the study. To that extent, you are correct in your calculation for Patient B. Remember, however, that all you know is that Patient B survived *at least* that long. Thus that is a right-censored observation.

What's important is to include for each patient, along with those "survival day" values, an indicator of whether there was an event at the end of that time period (Patient A) or if the individual had not yet experienced the event (Patients B and C). In the R [survival package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=survival), that's done with a `Surv()` object that, in its simplest form, combines the survival time with the event indicator.

Comment: Thanks for your help.